# Beginners Javascript Confusion - Forms To Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm learning Javascript & have set up the following test form, which I'm trying to input to the console when the submit button is pressed.  I'm not having much luck, can anyone tell me the issue?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="js/search.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="search">
      <p><input id="search-name" type="text"></p>
      <p><input id="search-submit" type="submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
$("#search").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = ("#search-name").val();

    console.log("Search Term Was: "+name);  
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this line instead. It looks like you're missing jQuery's `$`

```
var name = $("#search-name").val();` <-- Need the `$` or this line will fail (you should see errors in the console).
```

**Full Code**

```
$("#search").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = ("#search-name").val();

    console.log("Search Term Was: "+name);  
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Comment: Still not getting the output.  I've now edited it to the following: `console.log("search.js is here");
$("#search").submit(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 var name = $("#search-name").val();
 console.log("Search Term Was: "+name);
 return false;
});`

Comment: Interestingly, it does it when I put the javascript inline in the index.html, rather than a separate .js file?

Comment: @MrT probably not wrapping it in `document.ready` and placing code in the head so it fires before elements exist

Comment: @charlietfl so should it be inside the html document, rather than on a separate .js file then?  All that I have in my head is: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script> linking through to the js code posted above in search.js

Comment: @MrT no..need to wrap your code http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ ...will work fine in external file

Comment: You can have it in an external file, just make sure you include it at the bottom of your html file before the closing `</body>` tag. And wrap your javascript code inside `$(function() { // your code here });`. Take the time to go through this: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. Really understanding the code makes writing software much more enjoyable

Answer (score 0):

Add below statement after console.log

```
return false;
```